# Can we load environment variables from ~/.bash_profile without having to source ~./bash_profile?

Tags: python-3.x, bash, macos, environment-variables, atom-editor

I have a python script named `scraper.py` that scrapes information from the web on certain days. I automated this script to run on these days with a `cronjob`. Now every time the script runs, I want to send notifications to Slack to make sure that the scrape was successful. So I created a different script, `helper_functions.py`, that has the functionality to send messages to Slack. Now, because I am using an `API_KEY` that I can't share in the script, since I push it on GitHub, I stored it in `~./.bash_profile`. The script runs perfectly fine if I do `source ~/.bash_profile` from the terminal, but when I close my session, the code breaks. So is there a way to make it work without sourcing the bash folder?

Following are the scripts
`scraper.py`

```
import datetime
import helper_functions as hf


hf.slack_msg("Start scrape")

class IndexSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "index"
    start_urls = [
        "https://finance.yahoo.com"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        index = response.css("span.Trsdu\(0\.3s\)::text").getall()
        yield {
            'datetime'          : datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %X"),
            's&p_500'           : index[0],
            's&p_500_delta'     : index[1],
            's&p_500_delta(%)'  : index[2],
            'dow_30'            : index[3],
            'dow_30_delta'      : index[4],
            'dow_30_delta(%)'   : index[5],
            'nasdaq'            : index[6],
            'nasdaq_delta'      : index[7],
            'nasdaq_delta(%)'   : index[8],
        }

hf.slack_msg("End scrape")
```

`helper_functions.py`

```
import json
import os

def slack_msg(msg):

    data = {
        "text" : msg
    }

    webhook = os.environ.get("SLACK_API_KEY")
    requests.post(webhook, json.dumps(data))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An active line in a crontab will be either an environment setting or a cron command.  An environment setting is of the form,

```
     name = value
```

so you can add

```
SLACK_API_KEY='theapikey'

* * * * * scraper.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one idea:

- put the token in its own file, e.g. ~/.secrets/slack_api_key.txt
- modify ~/.bash_profile to do `export SLACK_API_KEY=$(cat ~/.secrets/slack_api_key.txt)`
- modify helper_functions.py to do `webhook = os.environ.get("SLACK_API_KEY") or open(os.path.expanduser("~/.secrets/slack_api_key.txt")).read().strip()`, which will first look for the environment variable, and fall back to reading the file if the variable is not defined

Comment: Hey thank you Czaporka! I tried this, but even with these changes when I do ```echo $SLACK_API_KEY``` inside the terminal nothing shows up! But anyways thank you for your time